# Spring projections without Spring Data REST

Tags: java, spring-boot, spring-data-jpa

`spring-data-rest` provides a fantastic way how to specify the view of an entity - Spring projections. I am curious if there is a way for achieving similar functionality without using `spring-data-rest` - just repositories and simple rest controllers.

Let's say I have an entity:

```
@Entity
public class Customer {

  @Id
  @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
  private Long id;

  private String firstname;
  private String lastname;

  // … 
}
```

and two controller endpoints. One should return the full entity and the second only subset of the entity (eq. just `firstname`, although the real example is a bit more complex). Basically, I would like to avoid returning nested collections from some endpoints.

I know that I can achieve this by creating a second entity pointing to the same table that contains only the values needed but the problem is that I would have to create a separate repository for it as well and it creates a lot of unnecessary boilerplate.

So my question is, do I need to have two entities with two separate repositories or is there some more elegant way how to do this in Spring?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use Spring's property filters to filter out few fields from response to an API:

```
@RequestMapping(...)
public MappingJacksonValue getUserEntities(...) 
    Page<UserEntity> entities = service.findAll();
    MappingJacksonValue mappingJacksonValue = new MappingJacksonValue(entities);
    FilterProvider filters = new SimpleFilterProvider()
                .addFilter("UserEntity", SimpleBeanPropertyFilter
                        .filterOutAllExcept("fieldName"));
    mappingJacksonValue.setFilters(filters);
    return mappingJacksonValue;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You could use [JSON Views](https://spring.io/blog/2014/12/02/latest-jackson-integration-improvements-in-spring) to filter out the fields you need. Here are some [examples](https://www.baeldung.com/jackson-json-view-annotation).

Alternatively you could create a DTO instead of a full entity but that is, IMHO an elegant approach.